# How to accept an out parameter in Ajax?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a static function in the aspx page with this signature:

```
   public static bool UserNeedsToBeAlertedPwdReset(out DateTime dtExpires) 
   {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.MivValue;

        return true;
   }
```

So I want to call this function from the client side, using the jQuery Ajax. How do I get a hold of the out value?

**Edit** 
Alternatevly I could check for nulls if this is possible with Ajax + jQuery like that:

```
   public static DateTime? UserNeedsToBeAlertedPwdReset() 
   {
        if(blah) 
           return null;
        return DateTime.Now;
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not create a function that returns a JSON response which you could include all the data you need.

I prefer to create .ashx handlers for these types of things and return a JSON response that is very to easy call and and handle client side.

Comment: +1 for suggesting ashx.  I should have put that in my response as well.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe it's possible.

You would be better written a class that contains the response data and returning that instead.

Comment: How would I marshall the data between server and client with that class type?

Comment: @Max ~ By using a JSON or XML expressive datatype. Are you really familiar with JSON/XML or are you just using AJAX by gluing bits together?

Comment: @drachenstern: No unfortunately I dont have any experience with JSON. Do I need to use JSON for this? I have put an edit in the post where I am asking if returning a nullble type is possible with Ajax, do you have any comments?

Comment: @Max you can use JSON or XML, JSON is just far more lightweight and self describing. Takes like 10 minutes to understand the structure then it's easy to use. Then you can use something like http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx to parse JSON to a class or a class to JSON.